Find the least integral value of $x$ such that $x^2 = y^2 + 2000$.

I successfully solved this question on my own by using a different method, but when I read the suggested solutions, I don't really understand the following part.

$x$ is the least when $y$ is the largest. Therefore, the difference
between $x$ and $y$ is the largest.

If $x>y$, $x$ is the least and $y$ is the largest, shouldn't the two integers be very close to each other and therefore their difference is the smallest? Can anyone point out the mistake I made in my argument?

Re your analysis, which is valid, an alternate verification is to manually check whether any of the following are perfect squares: $~{ ~2001, ~2004, ~2009, ~2016 ~}.~$  This can be done by noting that $~44^2 < 2000 < 45^2.$

$x^{2}=y^{2}+2000$ means that $x^{2}-y^{2}=2000$ which again means that $(x-y)(x+y)=2000$. Now apply A.M. - G.M. Inequality. That is $\frac{(x-y)+(x+y)}{2}\geq \sqrt{(x-y)(x+y)}$ which implies $x\geq 2\sqrt{2000}$ which implies $x\geq 40\sqrt{5}$ which implies $x\geq 89.442$ which implies the least integral value of $x$ is $90$.

@user2661923 : Thanks for your comment. But the least value of $x$ should be $45$ and the corresponding value of $y$ is $5$. The difference between $x$ and $y$ is $40$, which is indeed the largest among all cases. So I am not sure if the solution is wrong or not.

@Am_2099 Yes, my mistake.  I got confused.  I have deleted my first comment.

In this particular problem the rough inequality give the result immediately:
indeed $x^2=y^2+2000\ge 2000\implies x\ge 44.7\implies x\ge 45$ since $x$ is an integer.
And it happens by chance this minimum value is simply working for $y=5$, so you are done.

Regarding the statement in the book, it makes no sense simply because $x=\sqrt{2000+y^2}$ is an increasing function of $y$, therefore $x$ is the least when $y$ is the least too that satisfies the equation.
If you set $\begin{cases}x-y=a\\x+y=b\end{cases}\ $ then note $a\le b\ $ (because $y$ positive)
So $a$ represents the first column and $b$ the second one in the decomposition written.
$x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the least when $a+b$ is the least, so it is $40\times 50$ that sums to $90$ while all others sums are greater than that (e.g. $20\times 80$ sums to $105$).

Let $a= x+y$ and $b = x-y$ with $x > y$ and $a > b$
Then $a + b = 2x$
So $x$ is least when $a + b$ is least
And with $a.b= 2000$ then $a+b = 2000/b + b$ with $1 \le b \lt 2000^{1/2}$
Consider $f(z) = z + 2000/z$ where $1 \le z \lt 2000^{1/2}$ is real
Then $f'(z) = 1 - 2000/z^2$ which is negative for $z$ in the range.
In other words $f(z)$ is a decreasing function of $z$.
Then $2000/b + b$ which takes allowed integer values of  $1 \le b \lt 2000^{1/2}$ will be least for the largest such integer.
I.e. $a + b$ is least when $b$ is max.
$ \implies x$ is least when $b$ is max: $40$ in this case.
I'd say it was a misprint to state $x$ is least when $y$ is largest.
Should be $x$ is least when $x-y$ is largest.
(In fact, with $x^2 = y^2 +2000$ it would clearly follow that $x$ increases with $y$ and therefore cannot be least when $y$ is largest)

Thanks for your reply. Should $a-b$ be $2y$ instead?

Sorry, it was wrong. Correct solution now posted

(And typos subsequently fixed)
